# How to mock a specific function

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

So I am setting up a function but I have 2 different parameters which I want to try setting up and has different return values, how do I do that?

```
mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.Setup(x => x.AuthenticatedQuery(
   //It.IsAny<Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>(), First Parameter Function# 1: GetProfileByUpn Function
   NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB,
   httpClient))
  .ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessageForProfileRecordByUpn);


mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.Setup(x => x.AuthenticatedQuery(
    //It.IsAny<Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>(), First Parameter Function# 2: UpdateProfile Function
    NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB,
    httpClient))
   .ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessageForCreatedReturnResult);
```

so the 1st one should have a different parameters from the 2nd one, they have different 1st parameters.

I am setting up a single function called AuthenticatedQuery but has different parameters, how do I setup the different parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may not be able to distinguish between the 2 calls you show setting up. I'm not sure how you'd distinguish between the 2 calls.

You could try using [SetupSequence](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#miscellaneous) if you know the order of the 2 calls.

```
mockStateFixture.MockCouchDbClient.SetupSequence(x => x.AuthenticatedQuery(
    It.IsAny<Func<HttpClient, Task<HttpResponseMessage>>>(),
    NamedHttpClients.COUCHDB,
    httpClient))
  .ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessageForProfileRecordByUpn)
  .ReturnsAsync(httpResponseMessageForCreatedReturnResult);
```

The responses will be in the order you specify them after the `SetupSequence()` call.

I haven't tried this, so I'm not exactly sure `ReturnsAsync()` can be chained like that.

Answer (score 1):

Try FakeItEasy -

```
IMockedInterface mock = A.Fake<IMockedInterface>();

Object result1 = new {};
Object result2 = new {};

A.CallTo(() => mock.MethodName(1)).Returns(Object1);
A.CallTo(() => mock.MethodName(2)).Returns(Object2);
```

Comment: So you want different results based on the input params?

Comment: Yes, I want different results based on different input parameters

Comment: @DavidMcEleney Please read about [markdown](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). I've edited your answer to make code in it looks like a code. Now after your last edit it looks like a plain text. Simply add 4 spaces before code and you done

Comment: @Aleks - I'm on a bus typing on my iPhone  But I'll make more effort in future 